# How do I show proof of an e-Visa when I arrive in Australia?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia

I have recently applied for a tourist visa for Australia for my trip from India to Australia for 2 weeks in January 2018. I have received the visa-granted letter online. It is visitor visa subclass 600, which I [applied for online](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications).

Just after 1 week after applying, I received an email saying that the visa was granted and it has letter attached. On arrival at the airport, do I just need to take this letter, printed out? Is that all, or do I need my passport stamped by Immigration?

This is the first time I have used e-visa, and I just want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just take a legible print out of the Visa approval document along your passport.

> If you are granted an online Visitor visa (subclass 600) you do not need a visa label in your passport. Instead, you will be sent notification of the grant of your visa to your nominated postal or email address. Please keep this notification as it describes the conditions that apply to your visa.

As noted in the other answer and as apparent from the official source you do not necessarily need a printed form of notification but if you are a traveller like me or belong to the side of the world where people like me feel more confident with all the documentation with them please do carry one. Makes you feel good.  I have used some eVisas in different countries and just the stamp on that piece of paper is a good enough souvenir for me no matter how useless it is

Source: [Department of Immigration and Border Protection](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications)

Comment: "I have used some eVisas in different countries and just the stamp on that piece of paper is a good enough souvenir for me no matter how useless it is" In most countries, the printout is the actual visa and thus Needs to be presented and often stamped. In Australia, however, the visa itself is electronic, so the grant notification would **not** be stamped

Answer (score 5):

You just show your passport, and when they scan it the visa data will appear.

Printing the approval document **is not necessary**.

If you use a SmartGate, your passport will not be stamped, otherwise it will.

Comment: It's not necessary *in Australia*, but it's good to bring along for airline & security personnel who don't have access to the system - particularly in India, where your documents are usually inspected half a dozen times.

Comment: @jpatokal, [All airlines flying to Australia are required to use Australian APP](https://www.border.gov.au/Busi/Air/APP) which provides a board/don't board response. This is the same way the US ESTA and Canada eTA are handled and people don't generally travel with paper for those. Even in India I don't remember the many people who looked at my documentation checking to see if I had the right stuff to enter my next destination (how would they know?) except the airline check-in, and they would have APP.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, but I've still been asked for proof of Australian visa at checkin in airports like ZRH which don't have *direct* flights to Oz.

Comment: @jpatokal Oh yeah, ZRH. Most retarded ground staff I've ever dealt with regarding travel documentation, both Swissport and Dnata (I live there). Above all, they fundamentally misinterpret requirements for TWOV (airside transit) in certain countries